# Как правильно сказать: запатентовать изобретение или запатентировать?

Tags: употребление-слов

Как правильно сказать: запатентовать изобретение или запатентировать?

Comment: @НадеждаИ, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Вы собрались сжечь чертежи?

Если нет, то "патентовать".

Comment: Нет, не жечь)
Нашла в словарях оба слова. Может есть особенности употребления?

Comment: "Патентирование" - вид термической обработки стали (типа отжига).

Comment: "Для получения высокопрочной канатной, пружинной и рояльной проволоки применяют изотермическую обработку, которая известна с 70-годов XIX в. и получила название патентирования". А вот откуда такое название?

Comment: К сожалению, я не настолько хорошо разбираюсь в теории, чтоб понять, в чём там дело.. Но полагаю, что данный процесс (или - его результат) каким-то образом связан с латинским термином "patens" ("открытый"), от которого, собственно, и происходит слово "патент".

Comment: Ни в одном патенте, нет открытости, есть только идея, способная заинтересовать покупателя.  Купил, тогда скрытые эффекты реализуются за счет покупателя. вообще патент кот в мешке, для рисковых ребят с деньгами.
Запатентовать--отметиться в реестре идей, ничего более, причем с экспертизой чиновника от науки, может и не пустить, и это как правило, потому как идею можно перехватить по дороге.  За взятку. Но если интереса в силу непонимания не представляет, получается ПАТЕНТ. Потенция для тех, кто хоть рискует и понимает выгоду. рискни, я тебе таких в два счета настрогаю. НА веру.

Comment: В патенте - нет. А, вот, в *"документе, подтверждающем право первооткрывателя"* (первоначальный смысл "патента") - очень даже есть. И в *"открытом листе на должность"* (французская трактовка термина "патент") - тоже имеется.

Answer (score 1):

Глаголы патентовать и патентировать используются как синонимы со значением "получить патент", но патентовать является более употребительным словом.

Интересно, что грамматика позволяет использовать оба суффикса (ОВА и ИРОВА), которые в данном случае имеют  значение "наделять признаком или предметом, названным  мотивирующим словом".

В то же время указывается на то, что суффикс ОВА чаще используется при использовании заимствованных основ с отвлеченным значением: арендовать, интриговать, командовать, бастовать. В технических же терминах обычно используют суффикс ИРОВА: бетонировать, асфальтировать, хлорировать, никелировать, поэтому и на слух такой глагол  воспринимается соответствующим образом.

Comment: ...Вы бы хоть у Яндекса спросили...

Comment: Глагол "патентовать" образован от существительного "патент", которое заимствовано из английского ("patent").

Глагол "патентировать" образован от существительного "патентирование", которое заимствовано из немецкого ("patentieren").

Не смотря на внешнюю схожесть, это **очень** различные понятия.

Comment: Извините, я просто думала, что Вы знаете, почему для очень разных понятий используется одинаковый латинский корень, причем в обоих случаях заимствование из немецкого языка.

Comment: В первом случае (как и во множестве других случаев, связанных с юриспруденцией) - заимствование из английского. К англичанам - пришло от французов ("право на деятельность", у французов - "право на должность").

Во втором случае (как и, пожалуй, во всех случаях с "-ирова-") чётко прослеживается немецкий способ формирования наречий ("-ieren-").

Comment: У Шанского указано, что патент - из нем. языка, а Черных - из франц. языка. И всё-таки остается непонятным значение "patens" ("открытый") для отжига стали.

Comment: Черных, видимо, имел ввиду "офицерский патент". Понятие действительно французское.. Но! Пришло к нам при Петре, который французов "недолюбливал".. Скорее всего, "посредником" выступил английский или голландский.

Что же касается "патента" как "исключительного права на изобретение".. В государственных документах РИ используется термин "привилегия". В литературе встречается "патент". Но отследить заимствование на столь "хрупкой" основе..